# Why can a Scala trait extend a class?

Tags: scala, traits

I see that traits in Scala are similar to interfaces in Java (but interfaces in Java extend other interfaces, they don't extend a class). I saw [an example on SO about traits usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229743/scala-traits-usage) where a trait extends a class.

What is the purpose of this? Why can traits extend classes?

Comment: If you read the answer you linked, you'll see that traits are very dissimilar to interfaces, since they can contain implementations.

Comment: You might also be interested in the difference between trait inheritance and self-type annotations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses

Comment: Yes, I understood the point that traits, unlike interfaces can contain partial implementation of methods, but I wasn't sure about the purpose of traits extending classes (as explained in the example)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes they can, a `trait` that extends a `class` puts a restriction on what `classes` can extend that `trait` - namely, all `classes` that mix-in that `trait` must extend that `class`.

```
scala> class Foo
defined class Foo

scala> trait FooTrait extends Foo
defined trait FooTrait

scala> val good = new Foo with FooTrait
good: Foo with FooTrait = $anon$1@773d3f62

scala> class Bar
defined class Bar

scala> val bad = new Bar with FooTrait
<console>:10: error: illegal inheritance; superclass Bar
 is not a subclass of the superclass Foo
 of the mixin trait FooTrait
       val bad = new Bar with FooTrait
                              ^
```

Comment: Interesting.  But you can also restrict the classes into which a trait can be mixed by putting a type constraint on the self-type, e.g. `trait FooTrait { self:Foo => }`. When would you use one technique versus the other?

Comment: Scala gets pretty crazy with all the typing business. I can definitely see this could be pretty useful, but can anyone give any concrete examples?

Comment: @AmigoNico [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36945333/2032064) is one example when you may prefer inheriting from a class.