# Using object constructor of a trait

Tags: scala, constructor, traits

This is my class I am trying to create the following constructor for:

```
class StatsView(name: String, manager: AssetManager, statistics: Statistics) extends Node(name) with Control {
....
```

This is the object for which I am trying to use the constructor of Node

```
object Node {
  def apply(name: String) = new Spatial(name) with Node
  def apply() = new Spatial with Node
}

trait Node extends Spatial {
```

My issue is that Node is a trait causing this error message from the compiler:

```
trait Node is a trait; does not take constructor arguments
```

> trait Node is a trait; does not take constructor arguments
>
> class StatsView(name: String, manager: AssetManager, statistics: Statistics) extends Node(name) with Control {

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Traits can only extend other traits, not classes.

Comment: @DaoWen My issue is that I need to call the super constructor of Node.

Comment: @DaoWen Yes, they can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854941/why-can-a-scala-trait-extend-a-class

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - Thanks for the correction. The ways that the `extends` and `abstract` keywords are overloaded in Scala can be very confusing at times. I've always considered that relationship as a _restriction_ on the trait rather than an inheritance relationship, but I guess you could think of it either way. Anyway, I totally misunderstood the issue at hand (I thought he was trying to make a super-constructor call from `Node` to `Spatial`, not `StatsView` to `Node`). Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Node(name)` is just a method call and so can't be in `extends`. You need to write the type like this:

```
class StatsView(name: String, manager: AssetManager, statistics: Statistics) extends 
  Spatial(name) with Node { ... }
```

> My issue is that I need to call the super constructor of Node

Since `Node` isn't a class, it doesn't have a super constructor.