# why trait can extend abstract class?

Tags: scala

From the link
http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/117

It gives an example that a trait extends an abstract class.
Since abstract class has constructor, how could it happen? Does it mean abstract class and trait have the same position?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854941/why-can-a-scala-trait-extend-a-class
This relates to an abstract class as well.

Answer (score 1):

They are for sharing interfaces, fields and type between classes and both of them are not instantiatable. And a abstract class extends a trait and vice versa.
But since A class in scala can extend only one superclass,

```
abstract class A
abstract class B
trait AA extends A
class C extends AA // ok  class C's super class is A
class C extends B with AA // NG trying to have 2 super class
```

like I mentioned at the beginning, they are non-instantiatable.
So You do not need to care the abstract class's constructor.
It will be called when a class which extends it is created and instantiated.