# Scala mixed traits assignment compatibility (hierarchy)

Tags: scala, linearization

I have the following declarations of classes and traits

```
class C
class D extends C
trait T extends C
trait U extends D with T
```

and the following assignments:

```
val x1:C with T with U = new D with U
val x2:D with T = new C with U
val x3:D with T = new U
val x4:U = new D with T
```

The first assignment works, the others don't. **I want to understand why for both cases.**

As far as I understand it, the linearizations are as follows (`->` means `extends`):

- `C with T with U`: `U -> D -> T -> C`
- `D with U`: `U -> T -> D -> C`
- `D with T`: `T -> D -> C`
- `C with U`: `U -> T -> D -> C`

I drew the type hierarchy to get more insight:

[image: type hierarchy]

My understanding is the following:

- `x1`: works because the linearized types are the same (the order of `D` and `T` is not important for the type)
- `x2`: does not work because ...?
- `x3`: Does not work because traits cannot be instantiated
- `x4`: Does not work because `D with T` is a **super**type of `U`

Number 2 is where I'm stuck. It should work IMO because the linearization of `D with T` is `D -> T -> C`, which is a supertype of the linearization of `C with U` (which is `U -> T -> D -> C`).

Either my assumption that the order of mixed traits/classes is not important (but then why does the first assignment compile?) or my linearization is wrong or ???

Can you help me on this?

Comment: The type of `x2` is not relevant, it will fail even if you don't specify a type because `new C with U` is invalid.

Comment: Although this is not the problem, your linearization of `D with T` is not correct. It should be `T->D->C` because a trait is a subclass of the class that it is applied to (so that it can see methods of that class).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I edited the text accordingly. I am also going to mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks for that too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `new C with U` is not valid; the type of `val x2` is not relevant.

The trait `U` extends `D` which means *it can only be applied to a subclasses of `D`*. Since `C` is not a subclass of `D` the trait cannot be applied to it.

A trait that extends a class is similar to a self type, but with some subtle differences. See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854941/why-can-a-scala-trait-extend-a-class) for more information.